# Context with no props on class component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get contextApi values on some components, I tested on a functional component it works just fine, but on a class component the context appears to be empty.

**Context.tsx**

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

const FeaturesContext = createContext(undefined);

export const UseFeaturesContext = () => {
  return useContext(FeaturesContext);
};

export const FeaturesProvider = props => {
  let doc_lib_change_permissions = false;
  if (localStorage.getItem('doc_lib_change_permissions') === 'true') {
    doc_lib_change_permissions = true;
  }

  let np_upload_files = false;
  if (localStorage.getItem('np_upload_files') === 'true') {
    np_upload_files = true;
  }

  let document_library = false;
  if (localStorage.getItem('document_library') === 'true') {
    np_upload_files = true;
  }

  const FeaturesSwitches = {
    doc_lib_change_permissions: doc_lib_change_permissions,
    np_upload_files: np_upload_files,
    document_library: document_library,
  };
  return <FeaturesContext.Provider value={FeaturesSwitches}>{props.children}</FeaturesContext.Provider>;
};
```

**On the AppLayout.js (all of components run this component):**

```
import { FeaturesProvider } from '../context/Features';
<FeaturesProvider>
    **Rest of code**
</FeaturesProvider>
```

**On the class component that I'm trying to get the global state:**

```
import UseFeaturesContext from '../../../../components/context/Features';

class Index extends React.Component {

   static contextType = UseFeaturesContext;
   componentDidMount() {
     const features = this.context;
     console.log(features); //RETURNS A EMPTY OBJECT
   }
}
```

**What I'm missing?**

Comment: I endup fixing this just initializing the UseFeaturesContext with the initial data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using useContext (hook) with class component. Hooks can only be used with functional components.
With class components, you can use `static contextType = #ContextObject` and get the value of context, using `this.context`.
#ContextObject should be FeaturesContext in your case.

Comment: I tryed to do that, but still returning empty